# Dynamic c-style array. When to use retain, what to release and when to do it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management

In light of my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583280/real-table-component-for-iphone), I have decided to start of with a simple class to contain the two-dimensional array data.

The interface:

```
@interface DynamicTable
NSString ***data;
NSInteger _cols;
NSInteger _rows;
@end
```

Initializer:

```
-(id)initWithRows:(NSInteger)rows withCols:(NSInteger)cols {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        _rows = rows;
        _cols = cols;

        data = (NSString ***)malloc(_rows * sizeof(NSString **));
        for (int i = 0; i < _rows; ++i) {
            data[i] = (NSString **)malloc(_cols * sizeof(NSString *));
            for (int j = 0; j < _cols; ++j) {
                NSString *cell = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",(i + j)];
                data[i][j] = cell;
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Do we retain or not?
At this moment I am having a huge discussion with a trainee (who has developed for the iPhone before, where I have not) wether the assignment **data[i][j] = cell;** shouldn't be **data[i][j] = [cell retain];**.
The second version came from another sample here on SO. I have copied the dealloc routine from that same question.

Do we release on assignment?
The next bit of code is responsible for setting a new value in a given cell. Again the question arrises wether or not to free the original value (I already figured it's all pass-by-reference).

```
-(void)setValue:(NSString *)value atRow:(NSInteger)row atCol:(NSInteger)col {
    //NSString *cell = data[row][col];
    data[row][col] = value;
    //[cell release];
}
```

As you can see, I have commented out the bit that should be releasing the original value.

The whole memory management in an iPhone seems to be quite horrid. I have been reading quite a lot on the apple site and others about this, but it's a lot to take in at once.
Small examples with clear explenation usually work best for me LOL

Back to my question:
From my point of view (not sure if I am right) I should be freeing the original value that was put into the given cell. Can anybody confirm I am on the right track here?

PS I have been trying to use the Run with Performance Tool -> Leaks... But there too my lack of iPhone knowledge is holding me back quite a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with David, **stick with Objective-C** but I will answer your original question as that may help you transition into Objective-C.

The first example is done properly. The following returns a retained string because you called alloc/init.

```
NSString *cell = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",(i + j)];
data[i][j] = cell;
```

Your `dealloc` call will look similar to this

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    for(int i = 0; i < _rows; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < _cols; ++j)
        {
            [data[i][j] release];
        }
        free(data[i]);
    }
    free(data);

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Now for your second example you need to retain the value but also release the previous value.

```
-(void)setValue:(NSString *)value atRow:(NSInteger)row atCol:(NSInteger)col {
    [value retain]; //retain in case value is the same
    [data[row][col] release];
    data[row][col] = value;
}
```

I do not believe that [Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) is horrid in Objective-C and there is really only a few basic rules to follow with rare exceptions (`-[NSAutoreleasePool drain]` comes to mind).

Comment: +1, although your setter should make sure the new value and the old value are not identical before releasing stuff. If they are identical and this object is the only owner of the value, then your setter will cause a crash.

Comment: Ya your absolutely right! I Fixed it, I do not make that mistake when implementing @dynamic properties but somehow forgot here :(

Comment: +1, Thank you so much for this perfect example. Eventhough I have rewritten the code into David's solution, I have accepted this answer as it explains my question perfectly. And my mentioning of 'horrid' wasn't meant badly :) I am just having some problems grasping so much in a very short time.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to write some c code in an objective-c environment. If I were you, I would stick to objective-c and use c sparsely. This is what it would look like in objective-c.

```
@interface DynamicTable
NSMutableArray *data;
NSInteger _cols;
NSInteger _rows;
@end

-(id)initWithRows:(NSInteger)rows withCols:(NSInteger)cols 
{
    if (self = [super init]) 
    {
        _rows = rows;
        _cols = cols;

        data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //Release in dealloc method

        for (int i = 0; i < _rows; ++i) 
        {
            NSMutableArray *cells = [NSMutableArray array]; //Auto released

            for (int j = 0; j < _cols; ++j) 
            {
                NSString *cell = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",(i + j)];
                [cells addObject:cell]; //Auto retains
                [cell release]; //Release
            }

            [data addObject:cells];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

And here is what you would do in your accessor.

```
-(void)setValue:(NSString *)value atRow:(NSInteger)row atCol:(NSInteger)col 
{
    [[data objectAtIndex:row] insertObject:value atIndex:col]; //Auto retained
}
```

Comment: I have to admit, this looks a damn lot better than what I was writing. Eventhough the example I was using also included a NSMutableArray example, the best answer voted on was the one using c-style arrays. One reason had to do with the ease of access to the individual cells using data[row][col]. Another reason mentioned was speed, but I don't think anyone could actually measure a real performance hit unless we're talking about thousands of cells (which is not gonna happen). I am at least voting this +1, and if no-one else has another answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm still interested in that whole retain/release thing and wether my initial thoughts were correct (eg using retain on the cell assignment and releasing the previous value of a cell when setting a new value).

Comment: It's hard because you are coming from a non-objective-c/cocoa background. If you are going to be doing iPhone development, it is good too learn objective-c/cocoa.

Comment: @djBO I answered your retain/release questions in my answer. This example is the way you want to actually implement your code and there is no need to retain anything except for `data` since `NSMutableArray` will retain anything you add to it. The biggest difference will be the dealloc method. This example it will just be [data release] to release all of the strings created and my example based on your C array requires a lot more work.

Comment: @David & Joe: I can't make it +2 :( In the end, I rewrote my code and implemented this solution, as it is more appropiate. Thank you both very much! This has been an eye-opener...